# Upload UTF-8 encoded string as CSV to Cloud Storage

Tags: python, csv, encoding, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to upload a pandas dataframe as a csv to Google Cloud Storage. The code has to upload the content of the dataframe regardless of the characters it contains.

The problem I have is that when the frame contains special characters, such as Japanese symbols, Google returns an error that is difficult to interpret:

> Exception: Failed to process HTTP response.

The code itself is the following:

```
import datalab.storage as gcs
import pandas as pd
Items_Object = gcs.Bucket('astrologer-2').items(prefix=file_prefix)
     for item in items:
      if not item.key.endswith('/') and item.exists():
        data = StringIO(item.read_from())
        dataFrame = pd.read_csv(data, low_memory=False, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
        df_string = dataFrame.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
        print df_string
        response = item.write_to(df_string, 'text/csv')
```

The error fires on the line **item.write_to(df_string, 'text/csv')**.

All the code does is reading a CSV and trying to write its content back to Google Cloud Storage (in the future there will be changes made to the content)

The content of the file is

```
Nombre,Apellido
Lluís,Gassó
Test,Testson
最高,サートした
```

I tried using 'text/plain', 'text/plain;encoding=UTF-8', 'text/csv;encoding=UTF-8' and 'application/octet-stream' and none of them worked.

Does anyone know why is this error happening and how can it be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `datalab.*` namespace is deprecated, you should now switch to `google.datalab.*`. I believe there were some UTF-8 fixes there, can you give that a try?

Comment: As per the [cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Filenameencodingandinteroperabilityproblems) users with files stored in other encodings (such as Latin 1) must convert those filenames to UTF-8 before attempting to upload the files. Have you checked the encoding of your content file?

Comment: Thanks @yelsayed, I tried using the google.datalab.* namespace and I am still getting the same error. If I pass a string without special characters everything works just fine. When passing any special character Google's library raises the exception, no matter if I pass a utf-8 encoded str or a unicode variable, and regardless of the content_type specified.

Comment: @DSaini, the file I read comes from Cloud Storage as well, so is utf-8 encoded. I am also specifying the utf-8 encoding when reading it and printing the result which looks good, so this doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Seems like a bug with the stream writer then. I'd open a Github issue in `pydatalab`.

Comment: You may want to report this issue to [Google public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) platform which is meant for issue and feature request tracking.